# CQ5 textfield defaulValue getting changed

Tags: adobe, aem

I have this strange issue when I'm trying to set default for textfield.

```
<field
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    fieldLabel="label"
    name="./name"
    allowBlank="false"
    value="5350215250750013444"
    defaultValue="5350215250750013444"
    xtype="textfield"/>
```

But when I create new component the value inserted to that field is: `5350215250750013440`

As I have tried some combinations here are the outputs:

```
1) defaultValue=53502152507500134
        Output: 535021525075001340

2) defaultValue=5350215250750013
        Output: 5350215250750013

3) defaultValue=5350215250750013444
        Output: 5350215250750013000

4) defaultValue=535021525075001349
        Output: 535021525075001340

5) defaultValue=535021525075001399
        Output: 5350215250750014
```

It seems that the value is getting changed when it goes over 16-digits. It seems strange to me as it is a textfield value. Same thing is happening when I change field to numberfield.

Comment: Hello Krzysztof, did you come across a solution to your problem?

Comment: Not the solution but a workaround is to set a listener on that field and on first load (so if field value is ''), then simply set `panelItem.setValue('535021525075001344')`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `defaultValue` is probably interpreted as an integer when it is imported into CRX. Quoted from [section 11.5 of the JCR specification](http://www.day.com/maven/jcr/2.0/11_Import.html#11.5%20Determining%20Property%20Types):

> If the property type is not determinable from the node type assigned to its node then the determination of the property is left up to the implementation. For example, an implementation may use STRING properties exclusively, *or attempt to “guess” the type according to an analysis of the content.*

When the dialog is then created by Ext JS `defaultValue` is converted into the number data type of JavaScript. Numbers in JavaScript are always 64-bit floating-point values. Some of your given values exceed the precision of this data type and are therefore rounded to the next representable number.

However, you can force a data type for the CRX import, thus avoiding the problem:

```
<field
  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
  fieldLabel="label"
  name="./name"
  allowBlank="false"
  value="{String}5350215250750013444"
  defaultValue="{String}5350215250750013444"
  xtype="textfield"/>
```

Edit: Turns out that value is already too big for the JCR integer type and because of this never is converted into an integer in the first place.

Comment: Hi, thanks for detailed answer. Unfortunately this also doesn't work and still with defaultValue="{String}5350215250750013444" the Output: 535021525075001340. Do you have any other ideas? I would like to avoid setting a listener on that field but this seems to be the only solution so far.

Comment: My bad! I couldn't test yesterday and didn't notice that your value is already too big for the integer type in CRX, so it never got converted in the first place. Consider my reply irrelevant. It seems that the string is converted into the JS number type when it is loaded. (For example try to prepend a space.) Unfortunately, I have no idea how to idea how to prevent this conversion from happening.

Comment: @Krzysztof Krawiec the default datatype  is `String` when we provide any property like `property="value"`. I think we have to specify datatype other then String in `{}`, and it will not converted to `Number` or `Decimal`.  Please explain me if it does..

Answer (score 2):

The value we provide in `defaultValue` is shown as the placeholder of dialog, so that the author get an idea of what value has to be provided.

The syntax is `defaultValue="Placeholder"`. This value is shown till  didn't update it with your own value.

[image]

Once you give your own value no `defaultValue` will appear. Also, if its not  seen at first, drop your component again to see it.